# How to get last number insertion in SQLAlchemy | Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been strugglling with this question.

I am on a situation where I should get the latest information according to a number of its reexecution (not specifically ID) using SQL Alchemy.

Example:
I have a table and there is a column reexecution.
The registers in this table are related to a specific scenario. I need to get those scenarios with the latest reexecution number.

I tried to use `query.filter` but got not what I was expecting, also searched on docs and did not find something.

Comment: can you add more detail and explantion what actually you want

Comment: I edited the post, see if its more clear

Comment: sorry, didn't get your question

Comment: I need to get all registries with the highest number. If the latest number is 5 for exemple, bring all that contains this number

Comment: Sorry lads for not being clear. But I think @JonSG suggestion could work, thank you guys!